Heap Buffer Overflow in findMedianSortedArrays Function in C (LeetCode)
double findMedianSortedArrays(int* nums1, int nums1Size, int* nums2, int nums2Size) {  
    int* asd;  
    bool flag1 = false, flag2 = false;  
    asd = malloc(sizeof(int) * (nums1Size + nums2Size));  
    int br1 = 0, br2 = 0;  

    for (int i = 0; i < (nums1Size + nums2Size); i++) {  
        if (flag1) {  
            asd[i] = nums2[br2];  
            br2++;  
        } else if (flag2) {  
            asd[i] = nums1[br1];  
            br1++;  
        } else if (nums1[br1] >= nums2[br2]) { 
            asd[i] = nums2[br2];  
            br2++;  
            if (br2 == nums2Size) {  
                br2--;  
                flag2 = true;  
            }  
        } else {  
            asd[i] = nums1[br1];  
            br1++;  
            if (br1 == nums1Size) {  
                br1--;  
                flag1 = true;  
            }  
        }  
        printf("%d\n", asd[i]);  
    }  

    if ((nums1Size + nums2Size) % 2 == 0) {  
        double a = (asd[(nums1Size + nums2Size) / 2] + asd[(nums1Size + nums2Size) / 2 - 1]);  
        return a / 2;  
    } else {  
        return asd[(nums1Size + nums2Size) / 2];  
    }  
}  

Test casses are good, but it wont submit.
When I try to submit the code, I get the following error:
==23==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x6020000001f0
...
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow solution.c:16 in findMedianSortedArrays
...
I suspect the issue is caused by br1 or br2 exceeding the bounds of their respective arrays (nums1 or nums2).
I tried adding boundary checks for br1 and br2, but I still couldn't resolve the issue.
I also verified the size of the dynamically allocated array asd (it should be nums1Size + nums2Size), and it seems correct.
Is there a bug in the logic of merging the arrays or accessing their elements?
How can I ensure I don't access out-of-bounds memory for nums1 or nums2?
Is there a more efficient way to solve this problem?

Unrelated: You don't need to do any allocation to find the middle element(s). Even if you do use an allocation, you don't need it to have space for more than (nums1Size + nums2Size) / 2 + 1 elements

oh that is a great way of thinking thank you so much.

} else if (nums1[br1] >= nums2[br2]) { 

In this line, you will access an array out of bounds if its empty.
You are also leaking memory since you do not free(asd) before returning. You don't even need to do any allocation at all to find the middle element(s). Just loop to the midpoint and store the current low and the previous value (in case of an even amount of elements).
Example:
#include <math.h>
#include <stddef.h>

double findMedianSortedArrays(int* nums1, size_t nums1Size, int* nums2,
                              size_t nums2Size) {
    size_t totSize = nums1Size + nums2Size;
    if (totSize == 0) return NAN; // not a number
    size_t mid = totSize / 2 + 1;
    int prev, curr = 0; // previous number and current number

    // Loop for as long as there are numbers left in both arrays
    // and we've not reached the midpoint
    for (; nums1Size && nums2Size && mid; --mid) {
        prev = curr; // store the previous number
        // store the smallest number in curr and step the
        // pointer in the selected array and decrease its size:
        if (*nums1 < *nums2) {
            curr = *nums1;
            ++nums1;
            --nums1Size;
        } else {
            curr = *nums2;
            ++nums2;
            --nums2Size;
        }
    }
    if (mid--) {
        // We haven't reach the midpoint so one of the arrays must have
        // more elements. Fast forward "mid" steps in that array:
        if (nums1Size) {
            nums1 += mid;
            if (mid) prev = nums1[-1];
            else prev = curr;
            curr = *nums1;
        } else {
            nums2 += mid;
            if (mid) prev = nums2[-1];
            else prev = curr;
            curr = *nums2;
        }
    }
    if (totSize % 2 == 0) return (prev + curr) / 2.0;
    return curr;
}

Demo

thanks man, i didnt even think like that. Any tips how to improve my self?

@golub001 You're welcome! Oh, just keep grinding would be my tip. :)

You simply didn't check if there's a test case where one of the arrays was empty. If one of them was empty, you submitted code would simply check for the first index of that empty array (since you've initiated br1 and br2 to 0). Here's a fixed code that includes this case:
double findMedianSortedArrays(int* nums1, int nums1Size, int* nums2, int nums2Size) {
    int* asd;  
    bool flag1 = false, flag2 = false;  
    asd = malloc(sizeof(int) * (nums1Size + nums2Size));  
    int br1 = 0, br2 = 0;  
    if (nums2Size == 0){
        for(int i = 0;i<nums1Size;i++){
            asd[i] = nums1[i];
        }

    } else if (nums1Size == 0){
        for(int i = 0;i<nums2Size;i++){
            asd[i] = nums2[i];
        }
    }else {
        for (int i = 0; i < (nums1Size + nums2Size); i++) {  
            if (flag1) {  
                asd[i] = nums2[br2];  
                br2++;  
            } else if (flag2) {  
                asd[i] = nums1[br1];  
                br1++;  
            } else if (nums1[br1] >= nums2[br2]) {  //this is line 23 
                asd[i] = nums2[br2];  
                br2++;  
                if (br2 == nums2Size) {  
                    br2--;  
                    flag2 = true;  
                }  
            } else {  
                asd[i] = nums1[br1];  
                br1++;  
                if (br1 == nums1Size) {  
                    br1--;  
                    flag1 = true;  
                }  
            }  
            printf("%d\n", asd[i]);  
        }  
    }

    if ((nums1Size + nums2Size) % 2 == 0) {  
        double a = (asd[(nums1Size + nums2Size) / 2] + asd[(nums1Size + nums2Size) / 2 - 1]);  
        return a / 2;  
    } else {  
        return asd[(nums1Size + nums2Size) / 2];  
    }  
}



You simply check if one of arrays was already empty. If so, you return the non-empty list, otherwise you start merging. Submit the code and see yourself.

yeah, it works now, I'm new to the platform and wasn't sure if I had to take all the cases into account, plus code is slow as hell.

@golub001 as long as it has passed, you're good to go.

@golub001 you can always test some xases before submitting. Good luck with yiur journey.

ty i hope all the best for you
